# Get custom data attribute of clicked listview item; popup; jqm

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

i have a dynamically generated listview. Each list element i assign a custom data attribute. When the listitem is clicked it calls a popup.

```
            <a  href="#popupMenu" data-name='.$myrow[id].'  data-rel="popup">View</a>
```

//mypopup

```
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true"  data-theme="b">
                <li data-role="divider" data-theme="a">Options</li>
                <li><a id="one" onclick="func1();" href="#">Function one</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="two" href="#">Remove</a></li>
                                    <li><a id="three" href="#">Cancel</a></li>
            </ul>
```

I would to know the correct method to retrieve the custom data attribute of the listview item that called the popup.

//myjavascipt

```
  var func1 = function() {
        //display the custom data attribute from the listview click here
                 alert();
     };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

need to pass the event through the click listener

```
<li><a id="one" onclick="func1(event);" href="#">Function one</a></li>
```

use the event to grab the information you want

```
function func1(e){
 var role = e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-role");
 document.querySelector('#popupMenu').innerHtml = role;
}
```

Here is a working example of it:
http://codepen.io/positlabs/pen/DAtCL

Comment: I need to pass the listview item that is clicked to the popup, and then from the popup to the function.

Comment: I'm not totally sure what you mean, but i updated the code so it sets the html of the popup to the value of data-role

Answer (score 0):

I'm posting a JQuery based answer just because you included the JQuery tag on your question, and so, I'm supposing that you already have JQuery on your project. So:

You could simply use the `.attr()` method.

If that "data" attribute is on the anchor tag it self, it should be very easy (supposing all of the anchor tags have their onclick pointed to "func1()":

```
    //display the custom data attribute from the listview click here
    alert($(this).attr('data-role'));
    alert($(this).attr('data-name'));
    alert($(this).attr('data-rel'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```html
<a id="one" onclick="func1(this)" href="#">Function one</a>
```

```js
var func1 = function (target) {
    alert($('a').filter(function () {
        return $(this).attr('href') === '#' + $(target).closest('ul').parent().attr('id');
    }).data('name'));
}
```